# trigger my app and open email attachment

Tags: iphone

I have used CFBundleDocumentTypes and ask system to trigger my app when I touch the email attachment file.

It worked and my app worked as expected.
But how can my app get the attachment file handle to process?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same task a few weeks ago. You have to do it like this:

```
NSURL *url = (NSURL *)[launchOptions valueForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey];
if ([url isFileURL]) {
    //Do wahtever you want to do with the attached file...
}
```

Use this code snippet in the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;` Method.

I hope this helps you.

Sandro Meier